# Ubuntu running start jobs for hours now and it won't boot

Tags: boot

I have installed Ubuntu in virtual Box in windows 7 and it was working normally but after turning off the virtual machine and then turning it back on it showed a screen that said that start jobs are running and after several hours some of those are completed but it continues to run start jobs. I am an absolute beginner in Linux and I don't know what i must do.

This is the screen right now :
[screenCapture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NI1so.png)

Comment: When  you turned off the virtual machine, did you ask it to shut down gracefully (i.e. ask Ubuntu to shut down), or did you force it off? It looks suspiciously like it might be trying to [fsck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fsck) after a bad shutdown.

Comment: sadly i forced it

Answer (score 0):

- Connect to it using ssh
- Analyze what is going on: `journalctl -f`
- Run and add to your question `systemd-analyze blame`

Maybe some service should be disabled or reconfigured. Services have dependencies and for some reason if dependent service could not see wanted service started, it waits causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely you have a corrupted filesystem after a forced shutdown. Whether you can recover or not depends on a few different things, but it's possible that you can't, and may need to re-install.

There are a couple of options here, but the easiest would be to attach the live ISO as a CD in VirtualBox and change the boot order to boot from this. Once you've booted off the live ISO CD you can run `fsck` to check and possibly repair the filesystem.

First check the device of your installation:

`sudo blkid`

You'll get an output of block devices available. You filesystem will be listed here, along with its format (if you followed defaults, it will likely be `ext4`). For example, here is my SDD:

`/dev/sda1: UUID="c0773e08-b7cd-473e-817a-d02441f5e329" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="827e1d53-01"`

This means my SDD is on /dev/sda, and the filesystem is using the first partition. Assuming that you're something like `/dev/vda` and the type is `ext4`, make sure it's not mounted (`sudo mount`), and then you can run fsck on it:

`fsck -V -t ext4 /dev/vda`

I've use the `verbose` or `-V` flag so that you get some feedback on what's happening, as it can take a long time.

After `fsck` runs, it may still leave your filesystem unrecoverable. If that's the case, I'd say re-installing is easier.

One thing worth doing after a fresh installation is using the snapshot functionality in VirtualBox to snapshot the fresh installation before you do anything. It's quicker to recover to this than re-install.

Good luck!